# tideSDK in php module error

Tags: php, function, module, tidesdk

I created this function:

index.php:

```
<?php
 function hello(){
    echo "hello word";
}
?>
```

which works, but refreshing the page in tideSDK gives this error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare hello() (previously in .......)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: I fixed this problem,

using:

if(!function_exists('hello')){

  function hello(){
  
     .......

  }


}

//function_exists return true if the function exists else return false .

Answer (score 0):

the functions is save in the cache of the app,

if refresh the page, the app will the functions pre creates.

solution:

```
if(!function_exist("hello")){
 function hello(){
     echo "hello word";
 }
}
```